# How to use serial and bluetooth at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, uart

I'm working on a drone project using a mobile phone do send pitch/roll/throttle and yaw to a Rpi 4 2GB over bluetooth. This is no problem. But, then  I want to send these values to the flightcontroller using the serial port  (UART) (sending a bytearray at baudrate 115200). When run the program  I get no errors from the PI, but the flightcontroller won't get any values.  Is it at all possible to use BT and UART at the same time on RPi?

Comment: Hi @Svein-Tore Narvestad, Ah, let me see. Let me first summarize your config: (1) Android phone sends pitch/roll/throttle/yaw data to Rpi4B, OK, (2) Now you want Rpi4B to send byteArray data to flight controller, say PixHawk 4, by UART at 115,200 baud. (3) I think it is OK for Rpi4B to talk both BlueTooth and Serial UART at the same time. Of course you can verify my guess by doing the following: (a) Disable Bluetooth connect/pairing, (b) Test Rpi4B to PixHawk4 UART talking.  Ah, dinner time.  See you late this evening or tomorrow.  Cheers.

Comment: The information about which modules to use for the serial communication to work properly are missleading, to say the least. I was experimenting a day to get the UART to work, but now the BT is off - still haven't investigated further on this. However, the Pi4 has 4 Uarts, so you might not need to worry about the hasles of the primary one.

Comment: @PMF, Yes I remember in those old Rpi2 days, you could not use BlueTooth and UART together, and GPIO might affect 3.5 mm audio quality.  I thought there is no such restriction on RM3B+ and after.  I usually test Rpi on board UART and USB to serial adapter at the same time. And Rpi3B+/Rpi4B BlueTooth is still buggy, so I am not longer seriously using BT and UART at the same time.

Comment: @PMF how to use the other uarts, I only know about  /dev/ttyS0 and  I use that.

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm using flightcontroller KK215.  I haven't tried to disabled BT yet, but that my next try.  I don't fintd the BT buggy though, that part works perfect. But my android phone is sending every 70msecs, that might be too though?

Comment: @Svein-ToreNarvestad I haven't tried it out yet, but I guess it should work using `dtoverlay=uart2`, see /boot/overlays/README.

Comment: Have now tested a bit. Added dtoverlay=uart3 in config.txt.   Result: I lost the BT connection (not able to run sdptool.  To use bluetooth I must run the command sudo Sdptool add --channel=22 SP  The pi will respond with Serial Port service registered but not when I use uart3.  Tried to use uart5.  Then BT works OK, but I'm not able to use the serial port.  For uart5 TXD is on GPIO12.  Maybe there is a kind of conflict there, that GPIO12 is used to something else?  I get no error messages though.  I will try to test uart2 and uart4 tomorrow.

Comment: Finally it worked. I'l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This Answer is misleading, and does not answer the Question.
> It is possible to use Bluetooth **AND** serial - use `/dev/serial0` If you need to use UART0 it is still possible to use Bluetooth.

According to [RPi 4 overlays readme](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README) you have to turn off Bluetooth to use UART0. You should test alternative UART pins.

> Name:   disable-bt
>
> Info:   Disable onboard Bluetooth on Pi 3B, 3B+, 3A+, 4B and Zero W, restoring UART0/ttyAMA0 over GPIOs 14 & 15.
>
> N.B. To disable the systemd service that initialises the modem so it doesn't use the UART, use 'sudo systemctl disable hciuart'.
>
> Load:   dtoverlay=disable-bt

Comment: OK, summarizing, I can't use BT and uart0 at the same time.  Using Uart1 is OK, activating by:Info:   Change the pin usage of uart1
Load:   dtoverlay=uart1,<param>=<val>
Params: txd1_pin                GPIO pin for TXD1 (14, 32 or 40 - default 14)

        rxd1_pin                GPIO pin for RXD1 (15, 33 or 41 - default 15)

Comment: Finally it works. I'm using uart5 and fixed it with dtoverlay. Unfortunately there was an error in my code. I forgot to change from  ttyS0 to ttyAMA1