# Using Serial and Bluetooth device (external device) same time especially for using external BT dongle

Tags: bluetooth, serial, pi-4

I want to use Serial and BT same time on RPi 4B (Python)
I thought I cannot use it so I attached usb blutooth dongle (CSR4.0?) on it.
But I only can find references on the net using default BT when I try to find how to use BT function,

I found some hint on another question.  ([How to use serial and bluetooth at the same time](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105227/how-to-use-serial-and-bluetooth-at-the-same-time) )
but I cannot understand all how-to.

My question is
1) How can I do, if I want to use external BT dongle except from on-board one. 
(final goal is controlling by python)

2) Could somebody kindly help me to understand previous solution?
( [How to use serial and bluetooth at the same time](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105227/how-to-use-serial-and-bluetooth-at-the-same-time) )
especially How to setup the pins... 
Or at least some article to understand the solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The Answer linked is **incorrect** - at best it is a mis-interpretation of the situation. I use both regularly.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 or later](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) for an explanation.

The Pi4 has 4 additional UART which can be used for more demanding uses - See
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697